# how can i get my htaccess to make my url look like foo.bar/user with this snippet i have

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have been trying to get my urls to be more user friendly and I have come up with this set up

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ userpage?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

I added this to my `.htaccess` but I'm now i'm confused as to how to access these urls.

in my `index.php` when a user logs in i have tried to redirect the user using

```
userpage.php?user=s2xi
```

but the url parses as `www.foo.bar/userpage.php?user=s2xi` and not `www.foo.bar/s2xi`

and also tried this as a check to see if user exists (is there a better way?)

```
if($_GET['user'] != $_SESSION['username']){
    header("Location: no_user.php");
}else{
    //load page
}
```

I am using the Smarty template engine on my site and I have my 'themes' in directories that belong to members file

www.foo.bar/users/s2xi/themes

but i want www.foo.bar/s2xi to point to the persons profile page that is viewable by everyone else and not their accounts page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `.php` in your `RewriteRule`, if that's verbatim - eg, `userpage?` => `userpage.php?`.

However, you're going to run into some problems with this unless you're using a framework to help you distinguish between routes.  If you switched to using a separate URI format for user pages (eg `/user/foo`) you wouldn't have conflicts; but as it stands currently, using .htaccess to rewrite your URLs in that format could potentially cause problems with many other parts of your app.

To do it with a separate URI format, change your last .htaccess line (the `RewriteRule`) to:

```
RewriteRule ^user/(.+)/?$ userpage.php?user=$1 [NC,L]
```

may want to consider adding `QSA` as well.

Comment: oh, so if I don' use a framework my best bets are to use that new rewrite rule? um whats QSA?

Comment: QSA is another flag (goes in with `NC` and `L`) that forwards the query string along; so a url `/user/foo?bar=baz` would be forwarded to `userpage.php?user=$1&bar=baz`.  Otherwise the query string is not passed along.  And yeah - if you're not using a framework, I suggest using the new rule.

Comment: thank you, I'll take a look. Quick question. when I log in and my url foo.bar/s2xi loads, its not loading in page content. Any idea why?

Comment: If you're using the new RewriteRule, your url would be `foo.bar/user/s2xi` - you'd just need to update that accordingly in your app.  Is that what you mean?